# About Get google services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I created sign up with `Google+` into android app. When I test it give this message

```
this app won't run without google play services, which are missing from your phone
```

But I got the client ID and installed  `google play services`. Please Help me

Comment: usng emulator or device??

Comment: run it on real device or create Google API emulator.

Comment: check the answers given in that question